# How do I stop both my path animations starting at the same time?

Tags: animation

Hello I have been having trouble animating a scene. I know how to make the cars follow the path but my problem is that both of them start at the same time. The red car starts at frame 1 but I want the truck to start at frame 300. How do I do that? Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

The option *Fixed Position* let you control the position of the car from the starting point of the path (0) to the end (1).

To animate the position of the truck, go to frame 300 and set the value to 0, then press <kbd>I</kbd> to add a keyframe.
Do the same for the last frame of the animation and set the value to 1.

This method allows you to use the same path as a "Follow path" constraint for multiple objects.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that image needs to be quite so big...

Comment: this is the first screenshot I took with a new monitor (5k display). I will take it into account. Thank you

Comment: Wow, look at that clarity.